# A problem to get matrix limit

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Suppose that $A$ is a symmetric 3 × 3 matrix with positive entries, such that
the sum of every row is 1. Let $v=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3})$. What is
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A^nv
$$

My solution is: $\sqrt{max\lambda}=||A||_2\leq||A||_{\infty}=1 \Rightarrow $ all $\lambda\leq1$, but I cannot prove that all $\lambda<1$ which can lead to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A^nv=0$.

So I tried the second way and found that A could be regarded as a Markov transition matrix, but how to relate this to my problem?

Comment: Notice that it is possible that $A=I_3$, in that case $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}A^nv=v$. Also the value of this limit is a vector not a number.

Comment: @Mathematician42 the 0 in my argument of course is the vector $[0,0,0]'$. The problem says all entries are positive and therefore $I_3$ does not satisfy this requriement.

Comment: Okay, just beware that zero is also positive in almost all countries in the world excluding the USA. Good, then the question makes sense.

Comment: @Mathematician 42 Really? I don't think that is true.

Comment: Consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
0,9 & 0& 0,1\\ 0&0,9&0,1\\ 0,1&0&0,9
\end{pmatrix}$. The eigenvalues are $0,9$ and $0,8$ and $1$. Hence you cannot show that $1$ is not an eigenvalue in general. @smcc: It seems to be a difference between American and British textbooks, I know that many countries in Europe consider zero to be positive as well. There is no consensus world-wide.

Comment: Since $A$ is symmetric it is always diagonalizable. Hence you can write $v$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors. Doing so in my previous example shows that the limit is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A$ is an irreducible stochastic matrix with positive entries. There exists a unique stationary **row** vector $\pi$ such that
$$
\pi A = \pi \tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$
Additionally,
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A^n = \mathbf1\pi
$$
where $\mathbf 1$ is a column vector with all ones. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Finite_state_space).

Because $A$ is symmetric, the matrix$\ \mathbf 1 \pi\ $ is also symmetric. In other words, all entries in $\pi$ are equal, thus
$$
\pi = [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}]
$$
We conclude
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A^n v = \mathbf 1\pi v = \begin{bmatrix}11/18 \\ 11/18 \\ 11/18\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you tell me why there must exist a $\pi$ such that $\pi A=\pi$? In addition, how can you conclude that $A$ is an irreducible stochastic matrix?

Comment: @Gatsby $A$ represents a transition matrix of an irreducible Markov chain. To see that the corresponding Markov chain is irreducible, observe that all entries of $A$ are positive, thus it is possible from a state $i$ to any state $j$ (i.e., the probability is greater than $0$). $A$ is also a right stochastic matrix. In other words, entries in a row sum up to $1$.

Comment: @Gatsby If a Markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic, it is known that there exists a unique stationary vector. You may refer to the link provided in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helps!